# Alternative to Geometric Shader in OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: c++, opengl-es, emscripten, opengl-es-3.0

## Objective

I would want to render a nifti file in browser with better appearances and better frame rates. I have to use **OpenGL ES 3.0** in **C++**. This code is then being transpiled to **JS** and **Web Assembly** code using **Emscripten**. All I need in solutions in GLES 3.0

## Expected Outcome

I expect to pass some vertices(like in OpenGL) and each of these vertices is expected to be the corner of a cube. I think you could call it a voxel.

## Ways to solve in OpenGL 3.0

- I can use geometry shader to create more primitives from the point but this makes each vertex a voxel and is less preferred than the next method because of absence of interpolation. This method has an advantage of offering great frame rates.
- I could create a `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. It would take a size of `9*(no. of elements in vertex array)*(4 bytes)`. I ordered each index so as that a `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`  would create only 3 adjacent sides of a cube in each vertex. So each vertex corresponts to 9 indices(the 9th index being 0xFFFFFFFF `GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX`). I think there is a much better way using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`.
- The 3rd Method is using `glDrawArraysInstanced`. I not so sure if this supports interpolation between pixels.

## The Actual Problem

Rendering it as `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS)` itself gives me 25 fps(not enough). My probable hurdles are

1. Could I just adjust `gl_PointSize` in the shader code so as to eliminate the space between each vertex I draw and hence get a good 3D image without gaps?(I would need to zoom the object) If so, how would I code that.
2. I can't use `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` because it takes way too much memory and I have built with the maximum available (4294967296 bytes or 4 GB). So I have to get creative somehow(without geometry shader). If possible I need to interpolate color for each vertex to form individual cubes.
3. Any other much better alternative for this is well welcomed.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

I expect to get a solution which might enlighten me. For this to happen it must be something missed by me in the points listed above.

Comment: Nifti files contain volumetric data, if I'm understanding you right? What about using something like the marching cubes algorithm to generate a mesh, which you then send to opengl?

**edit:** Maybe something like this: https://github.com/neurolabusc/nii2mesh

Comment: @mortelsson The problem of mesh files to me might be:
1. I would not be able to make real world measurements in the mesh data.
2. I might have to generate meshes when I apply thresholding which may fiddle with frame-rates.(But please correct me if I'm wrong on this)

But nonetheless nii2mesh is still an incredible insight. Do you know of any straight DICOM to mesh converter?